# TCP RST Packet when delaying packets

Tags: java, linux, tcp, network-programming

I am trying to emulate artificial network conditions by delaying packets as necessary (application being emulated is a Java application).

The problem which I am facing is, the application detects that it has not received ACK for some time and re-transmits. This occurs at both ends causing a fission reaction. Packets are received out of order and eventually, one side sends an RST packet.

I want to make sure that this never happens. How should I avoid this?

Thanks

UPDATE: Some Wireshark capture session images: http://db.tt/fav2sRgL and http://db.tt/zGXwMubk

Comment: I don't understand the question. TCP doesn't behave that way, so if anything it is your emulation that is at fault here.

Comment: I turned off my emulation and produced an identical effect with "tc" (traffic control) rule. Same thing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are holding packets for longer than 1 second, which is a really long time in network land and is not something TCP will be happy with.  The failure cascade which results is pretty much what you should expect from TCP.

But first you need to consider whether that type of delay is really what you want to be emulating.  There is a big difference between the time it takes a packet to traverse a path (one-way), the round-trip time (there and back), and the time it takes an application to process and respond (independent of the network stack).

I've written a couple of articles on [network statistics](http://www.DataExpedition.com/support/notes/tn0021.html) and [emulation](http://www.DataExpedition.com/support/notes/tn0022.html) which you may find useful.

*Disclaimer: I work for a company which produces an alternative transport protocol.*

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on the intent of the emulation.

If you want wire-level fidelity, you will need to control the entire TCP stack to manage the timing. If, instead, you wish to simulate behaviour at the socket level, you can prevent the ACK storm by responding with zero-length segments that leave the stream unchanged.

Clearly, there will still be TCP segments, they just will not contain any payload.

The observation that the frames are sent out of order is curious as this would suggest an environment that includes substantial buffering. Are you doing the testing over a routed WAN, or on a single LAN segment?

Comment: I am doing this on a single PC. Can you please elaborate on your answer? I have also added two images to show the sequence of communication.

Comment: How? There is no way in TCP to aend a zero length packet, short of the libpcap API.

Comment: The standard sockets API permits a send() operation with a 0 length. This triggers a segment with the PSH flag and requires an ACK response from the peer.

Answer (score 0):

Retransmitting packets that haven't arrived is what TCP *does*.  Sufficiently out-of-order late arrivals -- specifically ACKs -- blow its synchronization-safety margins and it aborts.

Comment: So you mean that I should delay those packets that contain data? And let ACK-only packets go by without any delay?

Comment: ACK is metadata in the TCP header not a special packet.  If it has to the TCP will send a no-data packet just to get the ACK out on time, but not by preference.